# query last week of entries

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

In MySql workbench, this query works fine.

```
SELECT rooms.building, rooms.room, 
                         users.FirstName, users.LastName, users.adUname, 
                         userlog.id, userlog.timeIn, userlog.timeOut 
                         FROM rooms, users, userlog 
                         WHERE userlog.RoomId = rooms.Id 
                         AND userlog.UserId = users.id 
                         AND userlog.timeIn >=(current_date - interval 7 day)
```

When I run it from my code it will only work if I take out the last line,

```
AND userlog.timeIn >=(current_date - interval 7 day)
```

when I leave that line in it seems to complete the query, but then abruptly exits with:

> The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x11d8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread '' (0xa90) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x7b8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x13ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread '' (0xfa8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[1716] PeopleLogger.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Any hints on troubleshooting this one would be great.

Thank you

Comment: try (current_date, INTERVAL -7 DAY)

Comment: @Brian Thanks, but no luck. Same response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL... try

date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not catching some exception and that's getting you an error. Probably you're trying to access some row's data and after adding that condition you're not returning any actual data.